# How do I bind a method that returns an `Either` to a method that accepts an `Option` in Language-Ext?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, language-ext

For simplicity, I'm presenting a use-case that isn't really realistic (eg role-checking could be done differently, etc), but I'm trying not to confuse the question, so please bear with me.

Suppose I want to write a method that accepts an `int`, and needs to...

1. Check the authed used is in the appropriate role to make the request
2. Check the Id corresponds to a customer in the database
3. Check if the customer is active

If we get through all that lot, we return the customer, if not we return an error message.

If I use an `Either`-returning method for step 2, I can do something like this...

```cs
static Either<string, int> CheckUser(int n) {
  // Check the authed user is in the right role, etc
  // For simplicity, we'll decide based on the Id
  if (n < 0) {
    return "Not authorised to access customer data";
  }
  return n;
}

static Either<string, Customer> Exists(int n) =>
  // This would check the database
  n < 10 ? "Unknown customer" : new Customer(n, "Jim Spriggs");

static Either<string, Customer> IsActive(Customer c) {
  // This would check the customer, we just use a simple check on the Id for simplicity
  if (c.Id % 2 == 0) {
    return "Inactive";
  }
  return c;
}

record Customer(int Id, string Name);
```

I can then bind this together as follows...

```cs
CheckUser(36)
  .Bind(Exists)
  .Bind(IsActive)
  .Match(n => Console.WriteLine($"Success: {n}"), ex => Console.WriteLine($"Ex: {ex}"));
```

This works, but I can't help but feel that the `Exists` method should return an `Option<Customer>` rather than an `Either<string, Customer>`, eg (again simplified for clarity)...

```
static Option<Customer> Exists(int n) =>
    n < 10 ? Option<Customer>.None : new Customer(n, "Jim Spriggs");
```

However, I'm struggling to work out how to bind this between the other two methods. I thought that I could use `Map` to convert, but couldn't work out how to do this.

Anyone able to advise? Is it OK to use `Either`, or should I be using `Option`? If the latter, how do I fix my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ToEither](https://louthy.github.io/language-ext/LanguageExt.Core/Monads/Alternative%20Value%20Monads/Option/Option/index.html#Option_1_ToEither_1):

```
[Fact]
public void Answer()
{
    var actual = CheckUser(36)
        .Bind(i => Exists(i).ToEither("Inactive"))
        .Bind(IsActive)
        .Match(n => $"Success: {n}", ex => $"Ex: {ex}");
    Assert.Equal("Ex: Inactive", actual);
}
```

The above test passes.

Comment: Hmm, just realised that in my real code, all these helper methods are `async`, and if I replace the return types with `Task<...>` then I get a compiler error on the 2nd line of your code, where it calls `ToEither`. I changed that line to `.Bind(async id => (await Exists(id)).ToEither("No such customer"))` but now get a compiler error on the `id`parameter... _cannot convert from 'LanguageExt.Either<string, int>' to 'int'_. Are you able to advise how I would fix this? Thanks again

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel It sounds like you need stacks of monads, and possibly a traversal. Feel free to post a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I [opened a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72874733/how-do-i-bind-an-async-method-that-returns-an-either-to-an-async-method-that-acc), so if you have chance to look at it I'd be very grateful.