# How do I await code inside a method that returns an EitherAsync<T1, T2> in LanguageExt?

Tags: c#, async-await, functional-programming, language-ext

When using `TryAsync` in LanguageExt, you can do something like this...

```cs
static TryAsync<int> Divide(int n1, int n2) =>
    TryAsync(async () => {
      // Simulate some async operation that might fail
      await Task.Delay(300);
      return n1 / n2;
    });
```

I have the need for a similar method that returns an `EitherAsync`, but I'm stuck, as I can't find a static `EitherAsync` method to which I can pass an `async` lambda.

I know I can do this...

```cs
static EitherAsync<string, int> Square(int n) =>
  (n * n).AsTask();
```

...but that doesn't do anything `async`. If I change it to do this (simulate an `async` call)...

```cs
static EitherAsync<string, int> Square(int n) {
  Task.Delay(300);
  return (n * n).AsTask();
}
```

...then the call to `Task.Delay` is not awaited. I can't await it, as I can't make the method `async` (see [this issue](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/issues/1019) for more details).

I might be approaching this wrongly, but I can't see how you can `await` code inside such a method, which seems odd (to me, but that doesn't prove anything!), as the whole point of this monad is for `async` code.

Anyone know if it's possible to do something similar for `EitherAsync`? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any function function returning task should work due to implicit casts from `T` and `Task<T>` to `Either`, for example:

```cs
static EitherAsync<string, int> Square(int n)
{
    async Task<int> inner()
    {
        await Task.Delay(300);
        return n * n;
    }

    return inner();
}
```

Or you can manipulate with `TryAsync` mapping, which, I would say, is more correct approach because previous one will not handle exceptions thrown during the task execution:

```cs
static EitherAsync<string, int> Square2(int n) =>
    TryAsync(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(300);
            throw new Exception();
            return n * n;
        })
        .ToEither(error => error.Message);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, and the suggested improvement.

Comment: Just out of interest, is there any reason you newed up a `TryAsync` rather than using the static method like I showed. If you remove `new` from your code, it seems to work just the same.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel I wanted to show usage without static method. For me it does not compile without `new` (`Divide` also does not compile for me, not sure what am I missing, `Divide` compiles for me when `TryAsync` is completely removed to the left of `=>`, cause compiler will add `new TryAsync` in this case during compilation).

Comment: Do you have `using static LanguageExt.Prelude` in your file, as you'll need that to get the static methods to work.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel yep, my guess was that  forgot some static imports)

Comment: I'm a bit stuck applying your suggestion to my real code. I opened [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73100236/how-do-i-return-a-non-error-type-for-left-with-languageext-eitherasync), any chance you'd be able to take a look? Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

There is an implicit conversion from a `Task<T>` to an `EitherAsync<T, Anything>` and an `EitherAsync<Anything, T>`, so you can just create a `Task<T>` using `Task.Run` to run any async code you'd like for example:

```
static EitherAsync<string, int> Square(int n) =>
    Task.Run(async () => {
        await Task.Delay(300);
        return n * n;
    });
```