# How do I return a non-Error type for Left with LanguageExt EitherAsync?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, language-ext

I have a method that looks for a loyalty card in the database, and returns it if it was found and is valid, or an `enum` value if not. This allows the calling code to switch on the `enum` value. I want to return an `Either<TransactionRequestStates, Card>`, as the method will be bound along with several similar methods that fetch and verify the incoming data. As database calls should be made `async`, I'll need to return `EitherAsync` as opposed to just `Either`.

To clarify, I have several methods, each of which performs a particular step. If successful, each method returns a `Right` containing some data that is used by later methods. If not, it returns a `Left` with an `enum` value indicating what went wrong. I want to compose them as follows (simplified for clarity)...

```cs
public static async Task<TransactionRequestStates> Process(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        AppDbContext context, UserManager<User> userMgr,
        string cardSerialNumber, string uri, int amount, string hash) {
  Either<TransactionRequestStates, TransactionRequestStates> result = await (
    from card in GetCard(context, cardSerialNumber, amount)
    from deviceSerialNumber in GetDeviceSerialNumberFromToken(httpContextAccessor, context, userMgr)
    from device in GetDevice(httpContextAccessor, context, deviceSerialNumber)
    from rental in GetOrganisationRental(context, device)
    from vcResponse in GetVcResponse(rental, card, amount, hash, uri)
    from saveResponse in SaveResponse()
    select TransactionRequestStates.Success
  );
  return result.Match(_ => TransactionRequestStates.Success, msg => msg);
}
```

This question covers the `GetCard` method, as I assume that if I can get that working, the others will all follow a similar pattern.

I can do the following...

```cs
  private static EitherAsync<TransactionRequestStates, Card> GetCard(AppDbContext context, string cardSerialNumber) {
    Card? card = context.Cards.SingleOrDefault(c => c.SerialNumber == cardSerialNumber);
    if (card == null) {
      return TransactionRequestStates.CardNotFound.AsTask();
    }
    if (card.Locked) {
      return TransactionRequestStates.CardLocked.AsTask();
    }
    // Quite a few more checks are done in the real code. If we pass them all, return the card...
    return card.AsTask();
  }
```

However, this is all sync code. I want the database call to be async. Following the answer I got from Guru Stron in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72901808/706346), I know I can do something like this...

```cs
static EitherAsync<string, int> Square2(int n) =>
    TryAsync(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(300);
            throw new Exception();
            return n * n;
        })
        .ToEither(error => error.Message);
```

However, I don't want to return a `string` in case of exception, I want to return an `enum` value, as shown above.

I can't work out how to do this. If I try returning the `enum` value directly...

```cs
  private static EitherAsync<TransactionRequestStates, Card> GetCard2(AppDbContext context, string cardSerialNumber) =>
    TryAsync(async () => {
      Card? card = await context.Cards.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.SerialNumber == cardSerialNumber);
      if (card == null) {
        return TransactionRequestStates.CardNotFound.AsTask();
      }
      if (card.Locked) {
        return TransactionRequestStates.CardLocked.AsTask();
      }
      return card;
    });
```

...then I get a compiler error "*The type arguments for method 'Prelude.TryAsync(Func<Task>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly*". My experience with errors of this sort imply that my code is wrong, as if it were correct, the compiler should be able to infer the types.

I tried returning `Left<TransactionRequestStates, Card>(TransactionRequestStates.CardNotFound)` (with and without calling `AsTask()` at the end) instead, but that didn't change the error. I also tried adding the call to `ToEither()` at the end, but that also didn't help.

Anyone able to explain what I need to do to be able to return an `EitherAsync<TransactionRequestStates, Card>`? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why make things so difficult?

A stack of monads like `EitherAsync` mainly exists because it, itself, is a [monad](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2022/03/28/monads), and so defines a `SelectMany` method that affords query syntax (syntactic sugar). This is mostly useful if you need to compose multiple `EitherAsync` values with each other. That's not the case here.

It'd be much easier to define methods as returning `Task<Either<L, R>>`, because then you can rely on C# native `async` and `await` functionality. You can always use [ToAsync](https://louthy.github.io/language-ext/LanguageExt.Core/Monads/Alternative%20Value%20Monads/Either/Either/index.html#Either_2_ToAsync_0) and [ToEither](https://louthy.github.io/language-ext/LanguageExt.Core/Monads/Alternative%20Value%20Monads/Either/EitherAsync/index.html#EitherAsync_2_ToEither_0) to convert back and forth if you (internally in a method implementation) need the `EitherAsync` functionality.

If you do this, you can use fairly [idiomatic](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/08/03/idiomatic-or-idiosyncratic) C# to implement the desired functionality:

```
public static async Task<Either<TransactionRequestStates, Card>> GetCard(
    AppDbContext context,
    string cardSerialNumber)
{
    Card? card = await context.Cards.SingleOrDefaultAsync(
        c => c.SerialNumber == cardSerialNumber);
    if (card == null)
        return Left<TransactionRequestStates, Card>(
            TransactionRequestStates.CardNotFound);
    if (card.Locked)
        return Left<TransactionRequestStates, Card>(
            TransactionRequestStates.CardLocked);

    return Right<TransactionRequestStates, Card>(card);
}
```

If you want to convert it to `EitherAsync` you can easily do that:

```
public static EitherAsync<TransactionRequestStates, Card> GetCard2(
    AppDbContext context, string cardSerialNumber) =>
    GetCard(context, cardSerialNumber).ToAsync();
```

Comment: "_Why make things so difficult?_" Simply because I don't know what I'm doing, trying to learn this stuff and making a mess as I go along! However, with the help of clever people like you, I'm getting there slowly. Been reading your blog every night for some time, and am learning a lot, but am still having problems putting it into practice. Anyway, see next comment for more direct answer to your excellent suggestions.

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself clearly enough originally, but when I said the method will be bound along with others, I meant composed. I said "bound" as I was thinking of the `Bind` method. So, whilst your suggestion provides much clearer code than mine, I'm having problems composing it. What I'm aiming at is something like (simplified)... `await(from card in await GetCard("123") from device in await GetDevice("456") select TransactionRequestStates.Success).Match(/* whatever */)`, where there would be quite a few more methods called in between. However, this gives a compiler error, see next...

Comment: Compiler error is "_The 'await' operator may only be used in a query expression within the first collection expression of the initial 'from' clause or within the collection expression of a 'join' clause_". Any idea how I get around that? Thanks again

Comment: I updated my question to include the full query I'm aiming at. Thanks again

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Try expressing your APIs as returning `Task<Either<L, R>>`. Then, if you need to compose them, you should be able to use `from foo in Foo(42).ToAsync() from bar in Bar(1337).ToAsync() select bar.Baz()`. That should produce an `EitherAsync` that you can then unwrap with `ToEither` before you return it.

Comment: Had time to play with this properly, and it all seems to be working now. Shame that I need to add `ToAsync()` at the end of every line. Clogs up what is otherwise quite elegant code. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `OptionalAsync`:

```cs
static EitherAsync<TransactionRequestStates, Card> GetCard2(AppDbContext context, string cardSerialNumber) => 
    OptionalAsync(context.Cards.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.SerialNumber == cardSerialNumber))
        .ToEither(TransactionRequestStates.CardNotFound);
```

Note that this will swallow any exception and will return `TransactionRequestStates.CardNotFound`;

**UPD**

To handle multiple cases you can try using `Map` and `Flatten`:

```cs
static EitherAsync<TransactionRequestStates, Card> GetCard2(AppDbContext context, string cardSerialNumber) =>
    TryAsync(context.Cards.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.SerialNumber == cardSerialNumber))
        .Map(card => (card switch
            {
                null => Left<TransactionRequestStates, Card>(TransactionRequestStates.CardNotFound),
                // {} when ...  => Left<TransactionRequestStates, Card>(TransactionRequestStates.CardNotFound),
                { } => Right<TransactionRequestStates, Card>(card)
            })
            .ToAsync())
        .ToEither(_ => TransactionRequestStates.Failed)
        .Flatten();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this only handles the first case (non-existent card). I have quite a few more checks to do in that method. I showed one more in my first code snippet, and then forgot to include it in the second, which is probably why you missed it. Please can you show me how I'd handle the case where I need to check other things, like the card not being active, having expired, etc. Thanks again

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel see the update

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Very clever. However, I'm not sure how well it would work in my case, as a lot of the methods I'm trying to write here (see my updated question where I added the eventual aim) wouldn't fit with simple `when` clauses on the `switch`. A lot of them require a lot more code in between the branches, and even if I could fit that in, I suspect the code would end up very messy. Please can you look at my updated question and see what you think. Thanks again.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel you are not required to use `switch`, you can use ordinary [statement lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#statement-lambdas) (i.e. `Map(card => {...})`). Also you can introduce a new method to perform the map (i.e. `Map(CardToEitherMethod)`).