# How do I bind a Task<List<Card>> to Either<> with Language-Ext

Tags: c#, functional-programming, language-ext

I have devices (eg mobile phones, payment terminals, etc) that can request a list of cards held in a database. For security, the devices need to authorise themselves, and present their serial number in the JWT token. If any of this doesn't match up, we reject the request.

Thanks to lots of recent help with related questions, I now have two methods that I use in similar scenarios...

```cs
static Either<int, string> GetDeviceSerialNumberFromToken() {
  // Get the JWT token from the request header, and extract the device serial number.
  // If the token is invalid or serial number isn't present, we return
  // an error code (int). If the data is all OK, we return the serial
  // number. For simplicity, the latter is used here...
  return "abc123";
}

static async Task<Either<int, Device>> GetDevice(string serialNumber) {
  // Check if we have a device with that serial number, and some other checks
  // As this involves the database, this method is async. Here we simulate that...
  await Task.Delay(10);
  return new Device();
}
```

These are very simplified, omitting the parameters, etc, but that shouldn't affect the question.

In the current scenario, I don't actually need the device object, I just need to know that `GetDevice` returned it, rather than the error code.

Assuming we got past these two methods, I then want to get the list of cards and return it. I have a simple enough method for getting the list...

```cs
static async Task<List<Card>> GetCards() {
  // As this involves the database, this method is async. Here we simulate that...
  await Task.Delay(10);
  return new List<Card>();
}
```

My intention was to tie this all together in the same way I've done in my other scenarios...

```cs
var cardList = await(
        from deviceSerialNumber in GetDeviceSerialNumberFromToken().ToAsync()
        from _ in GetDevice(deviceSerialNumber).ToAsync()
        from cards in GetCards()
        select cards
);
```

As this would be an `Either`, I would call `Match` on this, and return an error code if either of the first two methods failed, but that part isn't relevant for this question.

My problem is that this gives a compiler error on the line that calls `GetCards()` "*Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List>' to 'LanguageExt.Guard'.*"

Following the answer I was given in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72875493/706346), I tried adding `ToAsync()` as follows...

```cs
from cards in GetCards().ToAsync()
```

...but this gave a compiler error "*'Task<List>' does not contain a definition for 'ToAsync' and the best extension method overload 'TaskTryExtensions.ToAsync(Try)' requires a receiver of type 'Try'.*"

I can't `await` the call to `GetCards()`, as you can only `await` the first line in such a query. I tried doing it the wrong way round, ie getting the data before the checks...

```cs
var cardList = await(
        from cards in await GetCards()
        from deviceSerialNumber in GetDeviceSerialNumberFromToken().ToAsync()
        from _ in GetDevice(deviceSerialNumber).ToAsync()
        select cards
);
```

...but that gave a compiler error of "*Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'List'.  'SelectMany' not found.*"

At this point I'm stuck. As usual, I imagine there is a very simple answer, but I can't see it. Anyone able to advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the

```
from x in foo.ToAsync()
from y in bar.ToAsync()
```

syntax, all values must be in the same monad. Here you start with `GetDeviceSerialNumberFromToken().ToAsync()`, which is an `EitherAsync` value, so all subsequent values must also be `EitherAsync` values.

This would be more apparent to you if you try to produce a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). When I did this with the code posted in the OP, I didn't get the compiler error reported, but rather this one:

> An expression of type '`Task<List<Card>>`' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type '`EitherAsync<int, <anonymous type: string deviceSerialNumber, Device _>>`'. Type inference failed in the call to '`SelectMany`'

I think it should be fairly clear from this message that you need to find a way to 'lift' `Task<List<Card>>` to `EitherAsync<int, List<Card>>`.

One option is to use [RightAsync](https://louthy.github.io/language-ext/LanguageExt.Core/Monads/Alternative%20Value%20Monads/Either/EitherAsync/index.html#EitherAsync_2_RightAsync_0):

```
var cardList = await (
    from deviceSerialNumber in GetDeviceSerialNumberFromToken().ToAsync()
    from _ in GetDevice(deviceSerialNumber).ToAsync()
    from cards in EitherAsync<int, List<Card>>.RightAsync(GetCards())
    select cards);
```

With the little I know of LanguageExt, there's probably a more convenient helper method than that, but that's the gist of it.

---

Indeed, things get a *little* easier if one imports `LanguageExt.Prelude`:

```
var cardList = await (
    from deviceSerialNumber in GetDeviceSerialNumberFromToken().ToAsync()
    from _ in GetDevice(deviceSerialNumber).ToAsync()
    from cards in RightAsync<int, List<Card>>(GetCards())
    select cards);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation (as usual). As it happens, the code I showed **was** an MRE, it was done in LinqPad and copied in here verbatim. The only thing I forgot to include was `record Device(); record Card();`. Anyway, it was `RightAsync` that I needed. As you've shown me before, there are a load of useful methods like this, I just don't know what they are, and hadn't managed to find this one. Thanks again.

Comment: The more covenient helper method is in the `Prelude`.  Same signature, but there's an expectation of having `using static LanguageExt.Prelude` at the top of each file.

Comment: @louthster Isn't that the function I used in the edited part of the answer?

Comment: I'm referring to `EitherAsync<int, List<Card>>.RightAsync(...)`, mostly I encourage people to use the constructor functions in `Prelude`.  So, `Prelude.RightAsync(...)`.  

`Prelude.Right` (for `Either`, not `EitherAsync`) also allows construction without knowing the Left type, which makes it's a bit easier to use without having to manually write out the generics; I'm yet to get around to supporting that for `RightAsync` but will eventually.

`LanguageExt.Prelude` is packed full of the common constructor functions - trying to act a bit like `Prelude` in Haskell.